# Combine the distinct column of same table in db2

Tags: db2

I want to combine distinct column of an one table, I want a column wise distinct.

```
SELECT  ALT_SRC_HOST FROM ATABLE WHERE ALT_SRC_HOST IS NOT null
UNION 
SELECT SOURCE_IP AS SOURCE_IP FROM ATABLE WHERE SOURCE_IP IS NOT null
```

output is coming, in one column. I want the output is in two column
expected output

```
ALT_SRC_HOST    SOURCE_IP
-               10.262.737.21
                1.34.34.112
```

Comment: Shure you are not looking for `SELECT  ALT_SRC_HOST,SOURCE_IP FROM ATABLE WHERE ALT_SRC_HOST GROUP by ALT_SRC_HOST,SOURCE_IP` ?

Comment: I have written a code for CLOB xml parsing using xmltext and xmlagg. Please have a look to post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326940/db2-distinct-xmlagg-query.  this is the same issue which I am facing. It would be really great if you can help me to solve this, We can't use listagg as our data is too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want it in a single SQL but this is an option

```
select distinct ALT_SRC_HOST as col1 , NULL as col2
from ATABLE
union all
select distinct NULL as col1 , SOURCE_IP as col2
from ATABLE
```

Comment: I have written a code for CLOB xml parsing using xmltext and xmlagg. Please have a look to post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326940/db2-distinct-xmlagg-query.  this is the same issue which I am facing. It would be really great if you can help me to solve this, We can't use listagg as our data is too big.

Comment: Ok you want it this way :-) - does this query work for you?

Comment: I need to check.. but is there any proper solution to fetch distinct data for query in stackoverflow.com/questions/6326940/db2-distinct-xmlagg-query post.

Comment: Thanks Michael!!!, ya that query works for me.. :-)

Comment: perfect so mark my answer as solution